# centering problems with bootstrap framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm noticing when i attempt to center this image, it is slightly to the right on the page. what is causing that? it seems like there is a margin added to the left of the image.

```
<head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>test</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css">  </head>

 <body>

<div class="container">
        <img src="dovelow.jpg" alt="Dove">

</div>
       </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `margin-left: auto;` on the `containter` causing that.

You should do something like this:

```
.container {
    width: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yuhJQ/1/